# Android on Virtual box RESET every time i boot

Tags: windows, virtualbox, android

I have Virtual box 4.3.6 installed on my pc and I have done all things correctly in order to run Android Jelly Bean and KitKat (4.2.2 & 4.4). All things are right and after full installation of Android, it reboots and asks to sign in and displays home screen. But after again rebooting, it again asks to sign in every time I start!

Comment: It looks like you created two user accounts, which interferes with editing your own question.  See this to merge your accounts: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Leave the account..., answer my question please.........

Comment: Without your fixing your account (which only you can do), there is no way for you to accept an answer or to comment anywhere.  I doubt anyone will answer without your being able to provide feedback on the responses.